# Comparison figure between Tomcat and TomEE,and other apache products

Tags: apache, tomcat

Greetings i searched a lot and read even more , it seem i cant get it right for some reason , because i finally found a comparison  according to figure
[figure of comparision](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html) but i cant understand why there is green check on tomee beside lets say JSF and not on Tomcat even i actually can run **JSF** , **struts** , other things on it.

So why there is no green check on Tomcat column besides **JSF**.

See the figure please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Tomcat can run everything, that tomee can run.  Including JSF!

The difference is that you have to add those libraries to Tomcat yourself before it will do it, or include them with your application, and hope they work well together.  Tomee has everything included by default, tested and certified JavaEE compliant, so you don't have to, and you can be sure that everything will work as the standard dictates.